# Moving ASP Site with COM+ to IIS 8.5

Tags: delphi, iis, asp-classic, com+, windows-server-2012-r2

Have an older classic ASP site with three COM+ processes that are accessed by the site to create PDF file reports.

Migrating from IIS 6/Server 2003 to IIS 8.5/server 2012 R2.  Both OS are 64-bit.  So far everything works, except the COM+ containers keep returning "there is no default printer specified" errors.

The process identity for the COM+ are all set to a local user for which I have set a default printer (Bullzip PDF for both).  They run in a separate process from IIS as well.  When I see the COM+ in the task manager as they run, they all show this user in there.  The COM+ are legacy 32-bit (written in Delphi) and have been properly registered, etc.

The IIS identity for the service is set to Local System for both 2003 (where it works) and 2012R2) where it does not.

Not that it should make a difference, but the old 2003 VM is on Amazon EC2 and the new 2012R2 VM is on Azure.

I'm trying to figure out why the COM+ is not picking up the default printer set for the process identity account.  All COM+ settings are absolutely identical between the two machines, except for the accounts, which have changed names but are both machine admins with default printers set.

What am I missing?

Comment: *"The COM+ are legacy 32-bit (written in Delphi) and have been properly registered, etc."* What do you consider properly registered? Have you used the 32-bit version of `odbcad32.exe` to register the DLLs for example?

Comment: Hi.  you listed the ODBC connector, but I registered with regsvr32, which is how you register COM components/OCX to the OS.  Hence the components execute but cannot get the default printer.  FYI, the components don't use ODBC to access the SQL Server.

Comment: Your absolutely right John, I did mean `regsvr32.exe` *(references to `odbcad32.exe` are a complete red herring)*. I've got ODBC on the brain today. What I meant was did you register using the 32-bit version which is found in `%systemroot%\SysWOW64` directory. The default on 64 bit servers is `%systemroot%\system32` directory which will register the DLL with the 64 bit registry not the 32 bit subsystem registry.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what version of Delphi? (And is the ASP layer doing a lot of work, would it perhaps be a nice fit for [xxm](http://xxm.sf.net/)?)

Comment: Hi - tried re-registering all of the components did not change the error.  The application pool in which this site runs in 32 bit.  The web site is ASP (VBScript); only the COM+ components are written in Delphi 5.  I can't yet migrate the COM components to ASP.net because the forms that are printed-to-pdf are not yet migrated out of QReport into something else (we use ComponentOne for our ASP.NET apps).

Comment: now I have more about this error.  I was able to circumvent the error by having the user logged on to the server at the same time as the process was run.

Comment: I figured it out!

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184291

You have to have the default printer set into the registry under HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT

Fixed.

Comment: Nice that you found the solution. Can you please post it as an answer and accept it? This way others will be able to find it? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to the question:

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184291

One must go into a machine account with the correct default printer, and export the registry keys from HKCU that correspond to ports, drivers and the selected default printer.

Then edit the .REG file to change **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** to **HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT** -- then you double click each to upload the new keys into the registry.  This sets up a machine default printer, and COM+ objects will have this information available to them, and **voila**!  The problem is solved.

Thanks for those commenters who helped me to get my mind into the right frame to look at this problem from the correct perspective.